# Оставить только необходимые цвета с Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, изображения, bitmap, обработка-изображений

Как в `Bitmap` оставить только необходимые цвета пикселей, а остальные превратить, например, в чёрный цвет?

Конечно, хотелось бы решение пошустрей.

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант - через `GetPixel` и `SetPixel`, но будет работать довольно медленно.

Лучше использовать `Scan0` и преобразовать картинку в массив `int`ов, соответствующих цвету каждого пикселя - для этого подходит формат `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` - в нём цвета представлены 4 байтами и в `int`е тоже 4 байта.

Ниже код обработки на VB.NET, его можно легко переписать на C#.

Этот код заменяет один цвет на другой, но позволяет при сравнении игнорировать альфа-канал (и сохранять его при замене). Если нужно какое-либо ещё условие, то надо заменить соответствующее сравнение и присваивание.

```vb
Public Shared Sub ReplaceColor(ByVal Bmp As Bitmap, ByVal OldColor As Color, ByVal NewColor As Color, Optional ByVal IgnoreAlpha As Boolean = False)
  Dim BmpData As BitmapData = Bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(Nothing, Bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
  Dim ArgbData(BmpData.Stride * BmpData.Height / 4 - 1) As Integer
  Dim Mask As Integer = If(IgnoreAlpha, (1 << 24) - 1, -1), NotMask As Integer = Not Mask
  Dim OldVal As Integer = ((((((CInt(OldColor.A) << 8) Or OldColor.R) << 8) Or OldColor.G) << 8) Or OldColor.B) And Mask
  Dim NewVal As Integer = ((((((CInt(NewColor.A) << 8) Or NewColor.R) << 8) Or NewColor.G) << 8) Or NewColor.B) And Mask

  Marshal.Copy(BmpData.Scan0, ArgbData, 0, ArgbData.Length)

  For Q As Integer = 0 To ArgbData.Length - 1
    If (ArgbData(Q) And Mask) = OldVal Then ArgbData(Q) = (ArgbData(Q) And NotMask) Or NewVal
  Next Q

  Marshal.Copy(ArgbData, 0, BmpData.Scan0, ArgbData.Length)
  Bmp.UnlockBits(BmpData)
End Sub
```